# CSS direct descendent selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm having a little trouble and I'm sure there's a simple fix for this seemly trvial question.

I have my HTML page setup with like the follow:

```
<ul class="locations">
   <li>
      Georgia
      <ul class="children">
         <li>
            Fulton County
            <ul class="children">
               <li>
                  Atlanta
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to style the "parents" list items one way, the "children" one way, and the "grandchildren" another way.

I've tried the following:

```
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.locations li+ul.children li{
    margin-left: 15px;
    clear: both;
}
ul.locationsli+ul.children li+ul.children li{
    float: left;
}
```

Where I want the "grandchildren" in this instance to float next to each other...regardless of how I work this our, `clear:both;` seems to be applied to both the "children" and "grandchildren" items. I also tried using `>` as a CSS selector with no luck.

Any ideas on fixing this? TIA

Comment: FWIW, the classes added to the lists are not directly of my doing, it is something done automagically within WordPress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confusing siblings (`~` or `+`) with direct descendants (`>`). Try this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVX3C/1/)

```
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.locations > li > ul.children > li{
    margin-left: 15px;
    clear: both;
}
ul.locations > li > ul.children  > li > ul.children > li{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't have any siblings at all, but from what you're describing you don't even want to use sibling selectors (siblings are elements on the same level in the hierarchy).  Essentially what you have will work if you remove all the `+`s, but you also need `clear: none` on the grandchildren.

```
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.locations li ul.children li{
    margin-left: 15px;
    clear: both;
}
ul.locations li ul.children li ul.children li {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pT8LA/

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP doesn't want the left margin on the *deepest* list item.

Comment: @henryaaron he can either add `margin-left: 0` on the last rule or update the rulesets to use `>` (child selector) between each `ul` and `li` set.