# Isn't text node a child when using children function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html code:

```
 <h1>
      When
      <!-- Green highlight effect -->
      <span class="highlight">banking</span>
      meets<br />
      <span class="highlight">minimalist</span>
    </h1>
```

And i wrote the following code in js:

```
    const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');

// Going downwards: child
console.log(h1.childNodes);  //prints text element(**When**)
console.log(h1.children);    // doesn't print text element (**When**)
```

i understand that *children* function prints only direct child, but As far as i understand, **When** is indeed direct child of **h1**.
Can someone explain me if i'm wrong?

Comment: "direct child" — Children are descendants but the reverse is not always true. "Direct child" is not a technical term in HTML, CSS or JS. All children are direct. There's no such thing as an indirect child. HTML doesn't do adoption, children out of wedlock, or any such thing.

Comment: @Quentin "direct" just means it's an immediate child.  It's not nested beyond one layer deep.  It's not uncommon terminology.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776379/css-direct-descendent-selectors

Comment: @Taplar — We have a term for that in the standards already. It's "child"

Comment: @Quentin Words change all the time.  Adding more specific terms to address your particular case is hardly harmful.  Especially in the context of when you talk about things like CSS selectors that involve the `>` operator, direct vs indirect children is extremely useful.

Comment: @Taplar — We have a term for "indirect children" already. It's "descendant".

Comment: In common language, a child is also a descendant.  I'll grant you that these terms mean specific things in the context of javascript, and people should learn them, however it is also highly possible that developers starting out in the field might find them confusing when used.  Again, words change.  Fighting against people using different words, regardless that their meanings are expressed (which is the whole point of language), is not worth the energy (imho).

Comment: "child is also a descendant" — Yes, and in web technologies everything that affects descendants affects children.

Comment: I strongly disagree. People and new developers should learn correct terms as fast as possible and not live in their bubbly dreamworld. Terminology exists for a good reason in programming and the terms *child* and *descendant* are by far not limited to the context of javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't text node a child when using children function?

Yes. Text nodes are nodes and can be child nodes of an element.

> doesn't print text element

There's no such thing as a text *element* (at least in HTML, [SVG has one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text)). Element nodes and text nodes are different kinds of nodes.

You're reading too much into the name of the property.

See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children):

> children is a read-only property that returns a live HTMLCollection which contains all of the **child elements**

or [the specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-children):

> The children attribute’s getter must return an HTMLCollection collection rooted at this matching only **element** children.

If you want to get all the nodes, including the text nodes, then use `childNodes`. DOM doesn't need two properties that do the same thing and it is often useful to get just the elements (especially if the only text nodes contain only white space).